# Some Confusing Shapes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Which teams played each other in the soccer last night?**[image]

Note: The ninth shape is meant to be entirely white, but contains a black border to let it be seen more easily.

**Hint:**

> Identifying the purple, red or yellow shapes should be the first step. The other ones will be harder to flag down...

**Hint II:**

> The yellow shape is the nose of a sun, while the black shape is a jewel on a crown.

Comment: Ok, so I suspect this is about ROT13(flzobyf sbhaq ba syntf. V oryvrir gung gur checyr funcr vf va Freovn'f synt, gur terra funcr vf n jvat bs gur oveq va Htnaqn'f, gur fha'f abfr vf va Netragvan'f, naq gur juvgr evat vf va Cnenthnl'f. Ubjrire, abgnoyl bayl Cnenthnl'f evat unf gur fnzr pbybe va obgu urer naq gur synt.)

Comment: Further insights: ROT13( 1) V unira'g svtherq bhg lrg ubj gur pbybef ner fvtavsvpnag. 2) Gur jnil yvar cebonoyl orybatf gb Ry Fnyinqbe ohg gur bevtvany yvar va gur synt vf ybatre guna gur bar urer. 3) Zber vzcbegnagyl, V srry yvxr jr nyfb unir gb tb guebhtu syntf bjarq abg bayl ol pheerag fgngrf, ohg nyfb ol pheerag aba-fgngrf naq sbezre fgngrf. Rvgure gung be zl svaqvat fxvyyf nera'g terng.)

Comment: rot13(Tenl -> Qbzvavpn?)

Comment: rot13(Erq -> Xnmnxufgna)

Comment: @Chengarda Nice spot :D ROT13(Vg vf vaqrrq gehr gung zl svaqvat fxvyyf nera'g terng; V fubhyq unir pbagvahrq gb mbbz va ba Xnmnxufgna. Abj vg frrzf fbzr pbybef ner fjnccrq? R.t. tenl funcr fubhyq or checyr, naq checyr funcr fubhyq or juvgr. Fb abj V jbaqre vs Cnenthnl'f evat va snpg orybatf gb nabgure pbhagel, ohg V qbhog gung fvapr gung jbhyq zrna gur evat vf abg havdhr, tbvat ntnvafg zl nffhzcgvba gung nyy funcrf ner havdhr gb n fgngr synt. Va juvpu pnfr, gur evat zvtug abg arprffnevyl arrq gb unir n flzoby gb fjnc pbybef jvgu.)

Comment: rot13(oynpx - zbagrarteb)

Comment: Boy, you guys sure have sharp eyes ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two football teams are ...

> ... the national teams of **Denmark** and the **United States**.

The shapes ...

> ... are details of emblems or coats of arms displayed on national flags.
>
>  **purple**: one of the **white** (silver) firesteels on the flag of **[Serbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Serbia)***
>  **black**: one of the **orange** jewels in the crown of **[Montenegro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Montenegro)**'s eagle‡
>  **green**: the **grey** breast of the bantam in the flag of **[Uganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Uganda)***
>  **orange**: a **red** udders of one of the cows in **[Andorra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Andorra)**'s flag
>  **red**: the **yellow** (golden) beak and breast of the eagle in the flag of **[Kazakhstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Kazakhstan)**†
>  **blue**: the **green** part of the rainbow, cut off at the left in the flag of **[Nicaragua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Nicaragua)***
>  **yellow**: the **brown** lower part of the sun's nose in **[Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Argentina)**'s flag*
>  **grey**: a part of the **purple** neck plumage of the parrot in **[Dominica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Dominica)**'s flag†
>  **white**: the **blue** ring between the sun and its rays in **[Rwanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Rwanda)**'s flag*
>  **brown**: one of the **black** wavelines in the coat of ars in the flag of **[El Salvador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_El_Salvador)***
>
>  (I had the idea that the shapes could be parts of flags after the first hint, but I couldn't identify them. The second hint confirmed that, but I owe the discoveries above to the keen eyes of oAlt*, Changarda† and JGibbers‡.)

The colours ...

> ... occur only once in the given shapes and in the actual symbols on the flags. In the order given by the shapes, the countries are:
>
>  purple: **Dominica**
>  black: **El Salvador**
>  green: **Nicaragua**
>  orange: **Montenegro**
>  red: **Andorra**
>  blue: **Rwanda**
>  yellow: **Kazakhstan**
>  grey: **Uganda**
>  white: **Serbia**
>  brown: **Argentina**
>
>  The first letters of these countries spell **Denmark** and **U.S.A.**

Many thanks ...

> ... to Changarda and JGibbers for identifying some of the shapes and especially to oAlt, who started the discussion in comments, who identified most of the shapes and who pointed out my errors in the course of trying to write up a sensible answer.

Comment: Agh I freaking knew ROT13( gur juvgr evat jnfa'g ernyyl juvgr ng nyy!)

Comment: Also, ROT13("Qnaznex" whfg qbrfa'g srry evtug– grpuavpnyyl vg frrzf yvxr gur oynpx abfr bs Netragvan vf npghnyyl oebja, juvpu jbhyq cynpr Netragvan ng gur obggbz. Guvf frrzf gb gvr va jvgu zl gurbel gung gur jnil yvar orybatf gb Ry Fnyinqbe, naq gur pbybe urer vf oebja ohg gur npghny pbybe va gur synt vf oynpx, juvpu jbhyq cynpr Ry Fnyinqbe va gur fcbg jurer Netragvan jnf (urapr fcryyvat Qraznex abj).)

Comment: **cont.** ROT13(Fb jr'er ybbxvat sbe gur flzoby gung vf oyhr urer ohg vf lryybj va gur synt bs n fgngr fgnegvat jvgu E. Gur enl bs Ejnaqn frrzf gur yvxryvrfg (naq vg'f gur bayl bar jvgu flzobyf ng nyy, ohg gur flzoby urer vf pheirq engure guna fgenvtug).)

Comment: Thanks, @oAlt: Good point about the nose and also about the squiggle, but rot13(gur fgebxr va gur E pbhagel'f synt zhfg npghnyyl or oyhr. Gur npghny pbybhef pbeerfcbaq gb gur cbfvgvba bs gur pbhagel naq lryybj jnf nyernql hfrq jvgu Xnmnxufgna).

Comment: (Oh wait, I misread some of your comments– if you read the newest comments I put here below your comment, disregard them. I deleted them for now; I'm editing them and then I'm gonna send here again)

Comment: No, @oAlt, those were good comments. rot13(Gur oyhr va E'f synt zngpurf naq vg vf n evat, juvpu V snvyrq gb frr, orpnhfr V fjn gur fhaornzf nf fvatyr bowrpgf, ohg gur pyrneyl sbez gur bhgre cneg bs n evat. Nyfb, V jnf n ovg obyq va hfvat gur evat sbe gur envaobj -- rira vs vg vf bar  -- vafgrnq bs gur npghny funcrf va gur synt.) I think we have it now.

Comment: Ah I messed up again, I don't know what I was doing there. I guess I retracted it since I thought I implied that ROT13(lbhe Avpnenthn jnf jebat, ohg va snpg V qvqa'g vzcyl gung ng nyy.) Whoopsies. Anyway, glad to know you still saw the comments since they didn't turn out to be wrong after all.

Comment: This is all correct! Absolutely great answer - good job to you, oAlt, Changarda and JGibbers! Congratulations on finding rot13(gur terra fgebxr va gur synt bs Avpnenthn - V gubhtug gung bar zvtug or gbb qvssvphyg gb svaq ohg lbh cebirq zr jebat)!

Comment: Yeah! Got it! I got as far as rot13(Q??ZR?X HFN) but missing just a couple of pieces to bring it home.